# Magento setup error . Redirect issue

Tags: magento-enterprise, installation

I have working enterprise edition of magento  site in my local machine.

I set up the same in the live with the same DB. But that is not working.

Showing browser errors like "The page isnt working" in firefox..

"page isn’t working, ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" in chrome.

And it redirects to www.mysite.com/install/

I have cleared the cookies and tried with private window also. Nothing helps.

Let me know if anyone faced similar issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Typically you will be redirected to the install page if `app/etc/local.xml` is not found, or has incorrect file permissions. Have you verified this file exists and has correct permissions?

This article can help with file permissions: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installer-privileges_after.html

Comment: Proper file permissions has been given. local.xml has been created. But still redirects.

Comment: Have you checked file ownership? e.g files should be owned by www-data if using the default nginx config.